# How to do mpeg/mpg to mov lossless conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

Does anyone know how to do lossless conversion from *.mpeg/mpg to mov?

I was asked to extract video from DVDs and do editings in FCPX, however FCPX cannot edit *.mpeg/mpg file natively, therefore I need a way to convert it from mpeg.

**I have tried two applications to convert mpeg files:**

a) **FFmpeg:** I used `c:v copy` to do file wrapping to Mov file, but the conversion was failed, each frame of converted video file is jittering. Looks like there're some information missed in Mov header.

```
ffmpeg -i {input_file}.vob -c:v copy -copyts -threads 8 -sn -y {output_file}.mov

ffmpeg started on 2015-01-30 at 16:48:48
Report written to "ffmpeg-20150130-164848.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -i /Users/yusizhang/Movies/DVDRemaster/dvd_1/track003.vob -c:v copy -sn -t 30 -report -y /Users/yusizhang/Movies/vod2Mov.mov
ffmpeg version 2.5.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  1 2015 20:24:48 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/tempdisk/sw --as=yasm --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --enable-avfilter --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-libutvideo --enable-filters --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument '/Users/yusizhang/Movies/DVDRemaster/dvd_1/track003.vob'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-sn' ... matched as option 'sn' (disable subtitle) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '30'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '/Users/yusizhang/Movies/vod2Mov.mov' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file /Users/yusizhang/Movies/DVDRemaster/dvd_1/track003.vob.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /Users/yusizhang/Movies/DVDRemaster/dvd_1/track003.vob.
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] Format mpeg probed with size=8192 and score=52
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] probing stream 0 pp:2500
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] Probe with size=2012, packets=1 detected mpegvideo with score=25
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] probed stream 0
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5005000 microseconds
[mpeg @ 0x7fbc5201dc00] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:4542608 seeks:2 frames:466
Input #0, mpeg, from '/Users/yusizhang/Movies/DVDRemaster/dvd_1/track003.vob':
  Duration: 00:58:50.56, start: 0.233567, bitrate: 2887 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0], 152, 1/90000: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 8000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x80], 157, 1/90000: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x81], 157, 1/90000: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file /Users/yusizhang/Movies/vod2Mov.mov.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option sn (disable subtitle) with argument 1.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 30.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /Users/yusizhang/Movies/vod2Mov.mov.
Successfully opened the file.
detected 8 logical cores
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc51501240] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc51501240] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc51501240] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc51501240] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc51501240] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc515008e0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x7fbc515008e0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fbc51501880] query_formats: 5 queried, 12 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[aac @ 0x7fbc52022000] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fbc5154cb80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fbc51501b20] Statistics: 4542608 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

b) **Qucktime X:** I use Quicktime x to open mpeg files and "Save" it into another file. I thought it would be a lossless conversion, but the color was shifting and I saw the bitrate of video was drop.

Is there any good mpeg/mpg to mov wrapper tool which can do the "wrapping" lossless? Or is there a suggested conversion method?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does FC not support MPEG-2 video in MPG container? That sounds ridiculous. Can you show your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output?

Comment: Hi LordNeckbread, I updated the description with ffmpeg command. FCPX cannot edit any file with Mpeg container... it really makes me headache.

Comment: You forgot the console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: ffmpeg -i {input_file}.vob -c:v copy -copyts -threads 8 -sn -y {output_file}.mov

Comment: That's the command, and I saw that in your question. I want to see what `ffmpeg` says after you enter that and complete the encoding. You can add `-t 30` to output a 30 second video so you don't have to wait long.

Comment: Just a guess, try without `-copyts`. Timestamps are different in mov (it doesn't use frame timestamps, it uses frame durations)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I pasted console output to the question. I tried withouut -copyts, but output mov file still has problem...

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to resolve this jittering issue. The root cause is that mpeg file doesn't have full PTS info. There's a closed ticket of FFmpeg talking about exactly this problem:

[FFmpeg ticket #974](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/974)

In order to solve this problem, add `-fflags +genpts` before the input file. Here is a sample FFmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i /Users/yusizhang/Movies/DVDRemaster/dvd_1/track003.vob -c:a copy -c:v copy -threads 8 -sn -y /Users/yusizhang/Movies/vod2Mov_clean/Episode1_clean.mov
```

Comment: I re-opened the FFmpeg ticket, retitled it to: `genpts not enabled automatically when remuxing from VOB to MOV`.  It's silly that users have to run into a problem and then discover an obscure option.

Comment: Great retitled, I totally agree with it. Hope FFmpeg developers can take it into consideration. Thank you!

Comment: did they ever fix this?